# How to number frametitles

Tags: beamer

I have a simple `beamer` presentation, with a Title frame (that is info on author, date, etc), and several sections with associated titleframes.
I would like to split this presentation into parts and number them accordingly, so the following structure results:

> Title
>
> additional frame, associated with title (unnumbered)
>
> 1 Section
>
> 1.1 first titleframe
>
> 1.2 second titleframe
>
> 2 Section
>
> 2.1 ...
>
> 2.2 ...

How can this be done? The Title should not be numbered, nor associated frames. Only sections, subsections, etc. Would also be nice if the "numbering" of a section could be toggled between on/off, but that is more optional.

Edit: The numbering does not have to be over the sections. If there is an easier way, I am open for anything.

I got the following:

```
\documentclass[xcolor= pdftex, dvipsnames, table, 10pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Default}
    %\usetheme{Madrid}
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
    \usecolortheme{whale}
}

\AtBeginSection[]{
    \begin{frame}
        \vfill
        \centering
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=false,rounded=true]{title}
            \usebeamerfont{title}\secname\par%
        \end{beamercolorbox}
        \vfill
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document} 

\title{Title} 
\author{Author}
\institute{Firm}
\date{Date} 

\setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=false]
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=false,shadow=false]
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\frame{\titlepage}

\section{First section}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}
    \framesubtitle{Subtitle}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}
    \framesubtitle{Subtitle}
\end{frame}

\section{Second section}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}
    \framesubtitle{Subtitle}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}
    \framesubtitle{Subtitle}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Please tell me if any information is missing or if the above question is unclear in any regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick and dirty solution I can suggest redefining `\frametitle` to put the frame number directly to the frame title. I guess that the proper solution would be to redefine the outer theme template for the frame title.

The changes include adding `\thesection` to your section frames and a few lines after that which do the definition of the frame counter and adding it to the titles.

```
\documentclass[xcolor= pdftex, dvipsnames, table, 10pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
    %\usetheme{Default}
    %\usetheme{Madrid}
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
    \usecolortheme{whale}
}

\AtBeginSection[]{
    \begin{frame}
        \vfill
        \centering
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=false,rounded=true]{title}
            \usebeamerfont{title}\thesection\ \secname\par%
        \end{beamercolorbox}
        \vfill
    \end{frame}
}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{frame}[section]
\def\theframe{\thesection.\arabic{frame}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{frame}{}
\let\frametitleold\frametitle
\def\frametitle#1{%
  \refstepcounter{frame}%
  \ifnum\c@section=0
    \frametitleold{#1}%
  \else
    \frametitleold{\theframe\ #1}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 

\title{Title} 
\author{Author}
\institute{Firm}
\date{Date} 

\setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=false]
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=false,shadow=false]
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}
    \framesubtitle{Subtitle}
\end{frame}

\section{First section}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}
    \framesubtitle{Subtitle}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}
    \framesubtitle{Subtitle}
\end{frame}

\section{Second section}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}
    \framesubtitle{Subtitle}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}
    \framesubtitle{Subtitle}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly for me.

Comment: Just one question remains: Is it possible that one frame within a certain level, lets say "1", does not get a new number?
So for example the structure within a certain section would be: 1.1, 1.2, 1.2, 1.3, ... (1.2  two times, as the topic is the same for 2 frames)

Comment: You can always decrease the frame counter between two frames.

Comment: Alright, you mean by using `[noframenumbering]` I assume?

Comment: No, I mean `addtocounter{frame}{-1}` between frames with the same desired number.

Comment: Ok that works. Very last question from me, sorry but I noticed just now. At the end of my presentation I am using `\printbibliography` for the bib. I did not include it above, as I thought it would make things needlessly complicated. Adapting the code to also account for biblatex would probably be too complicated, but is there any way to simply deactivate the above definition at the end? From my understanding `\def\theframe{\thesection.\arabic{frame}}` is permanent if defined at the top?

Comment: You can do just `\let\frametitle\frametitleold` before the bibliography.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much for all the replies.